# apache robots.txt with SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, robots.txt

I have an .htaccess file with a rewrite rule to get a redirect of every HTTP request to HTTPS.

But now I have a problem that my robots.txt is not recognized by some online checker.
If I remove the redirect from the .htaccess file the robots.txt is recognized correctly.

Maybe I should exclude that the robots.txt is redirects to an HTTPS connection?

This is the part of .htaccess for redirecting to HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$            
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about including this rule:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^robots.txt$`

That should only trigger for requests that aren't for robots.txt...

Comment: Thank you. I think there should be a $1 between RewriteCond and ! but than this is working.

Comment: whoops, yeah.  I edited my otherwise sloppy answer.  I think the Request_URI bit is probably a bit better method.